# Integrate this Gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^N$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

I'm trying to compute this integral:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \exp\Big((\vec{x} - \vec{\mu})^T(\lambda \text{A}^T \text{A}+\delta \text{L})(\vec{x} - \vec{\mu}) + U(\delta)\Big)d\vec{x}$$

Where $$\mu = (\lambda \text{A}^T \text{A}+\delta \text{L})^{-1}\lambda \text{A}^T\vec{b} \ $$ and $$U(\delta) = \lambda^2\vec{b}^T\text{A}(\lambda \text{A}^T \text{A}+\delta \text{L})^{-1}\text{A}^T\vec{b}.$$

**What I Have Tried So Far:**

Obviously, $U(\delta) \ $ doesn't depend on $\vec{x}$ and can thus be brought outside the integral.  I can also expand the exponent.  After that I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\lambda A^T A + \delta L$ is positive definite:

The density of a n-dimensional Gaussian with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and mean $\mu$ is $f(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{ (2 \pi)^{n/2} |\Sigma|^{1/2}} e^{-(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1} (\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R^n}} e^{-(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})^T \Sigma^{-1} (\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})} = (2 \pi)^{n/2} |\Sigma|^{1/2} $ since $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(\vec{x}) = 1$.

Thus, if we pull out $e^{U(\delta)}$ from the integral, and match form to the Gaussian with $\Sigma^{-1} = \lambda A^T A + \delta L$ and mean $\vec{\mu}$, we can compare to the multivariate Gaussian, and see that it is $e^{U(\delta)} (2 \pi)^{n/2} |\Sigma|^{1/2} = e^{U(\delta)} (2 \pi)^{n/2} |\lambda A^T A + \delta L|^{-1/2}$